# "A teaching assistant in/of/for Applied Quantitative Methods"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, collocation, of-for, in-of

> I am a Teaching Assistant in/of/for Applied Quantitative Methods

Which preposition is correct this context? And why?

Comment: I don't think any of those three are wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what is *Applied Quantitative Methods*. If it's the exact name of a course, I would say:

I am a teaching assistant for the course *Applied Quantitative Methods*.

You can also put the course name inside quotations. Above is how I wrote it my resume.

If *Applied Quantitative Methods* is an area of research, it would be better to use *in*.

*Of* can also be used in some other cases like: *I am a teaching assistant of Prof. Davis.*